# How to select the dropdown value by reading from csv file

Tags: python, selenium, drop-down-menu

I have a  file containing State and city as a CSV File.

Here is one sample CSV File,

```
ALABAMA,ANNISTON
ARIZONA,GLOBE
```

I have a dropdown box which contains the Cities. 
Please find the format of cities in dropdown below,

```
ANNISTON (362)
GLOBE (385-480)
```

Now i want to select the cities from the dropdown which are in the csv file.
Here is what i tried,

```
with open("statecity.csv") as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    for line in csvreader:
        State_Name = line[0]
        City_Name = line[1]
        cityid = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('Location_CityId'))
        try:
            cityid.select_by_visible_text(City_Name)
            print City_Name +" " + "FOUND"
        except:
            print City_Name +" " + "NOT FOUND"
```

Error am getting because in **csv file city name is like "ANNISTON"** but in **dropdown it is like "ANNISTON (362) "**

I want to eliminate the number after the city name in dropdown during matchiing. Then only cityname will get matched from the csv file with respect to cityname in the dropbox.

Basically am doing it for extracting the data. 
Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do a partial text match or remove the number from the string. What you could do is iterate through the available options until you find a match. Maybe something like this:

```
...
# Grab the select box with selenium, same as you had before
cityid = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('Location_CityId'))

# Iterate through the available dropdown items
for option in cityid.options:
    # Grab the value of the current dropdown

    ### NOT USED -> This is for getting the option value, not the text
    # option_value = option.get_attribute('value')
    option_text = option.text

    # Check if the city you're currently looking for matches the current dropdown
    if City_Name in option_text:
        # If it does match, click on that item
        option.click()
        # Break out of the loop since we found what we're looking for
        break
```

Comment: It worked for first state city from csv file
But it didn't work for Second State city can i know why it is selecting someother city instead of GLOBE city from dropdown box

Comment: Also could you please comment in your code what each line does it

Comment: You may have to match it more closely than in the example I gave. For example, if your city is "London" and the dropdown contains entries for "London, Canada" and "London, UK" then it will find the first one only.  It also won't work if you get no matches. For example, if a city is on your spreadsheet but not in your dropdown, nothing will get clicked on. What's the 2nd city that you're trying to match, and what are the entries of the dropdown?

Comment: Second State , city is ALABAMA,MESA/TEMPE

Comment: Why it selects only first one only. What makes the code to decide like that ?

Comment: What is the value attribute of the <option> element in the dropdown corresponding to Alabama, Mesa/Tempte. Maybe you can post an image of the inspect element portion of the page?

Comment: <span style="width: 143px; user-select: none;">MESA/TEMPE (852)</span>

<option value="400">MESA/TEMPE (852)</option>

Comment: That's not an <option> element contained in the dropdown, that seems to be from a different part of the page. An option can't have child elements.

Comment: Mind posting the relevant source code of that portion of the page? Maybe everything contained within the <select> tag? You can do right click > inspect element > edit as HTML > copy text

Comment: <option value="400">MESA/TEMPE (852)</option>
This is the one you were looking for

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159525/discussion-between-venkat-and-robert-townley).

Comment: OHH okay got it. I had assumed that the option value and displayed text were the same. That's not the case. You want to look at option.text instead of option value. I'll edit the answer

Comment: Yeah, Hurray got it where was the misconception. Thanks Buddy

Comment: Awesome, glad it helped! If you're all set, mind accepting the answer?